# how to display uploaded file in yii2 views and interact with it?

Tags: file, view, upload, yii2, display

I added file uploading function to my controller, file is stored in the specified directory, but views like update, index, view shows only the name of the file. I need a link or a button to interact with this uploaded file. For example opening file by pressing on this link or button also downloading this file. Could you help me with it?

Model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
    ...
        [['attachment'],'file'],
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Letter();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->attachment = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'attachment');

        $filename = pathinfo($model->attachment , PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $ext = pathinfo($model->attachment , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $newFname = $filename.'.'.$ext;

        $path=Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/uploads/';
        if(!empty($newFname)){
            $model->attachment->saveAs($path.$newFname);
            $model->attachment = $newFname;
            if($model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
```

Form View:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
...

<?= $form->field($model, 'attachment')->fileInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your form view like below:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
...

<?= $form->field($model, 'attachment')->fileInput() ?>

 /*link to download file*/
<?if(!$model->isNewRecord):?>
<?= Html::a('Download file', ['download', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?endif;?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>


<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

in your controller add new action for download file:

```
public function actionDownload($id) 
{ 
    $download = Letter::findOne($id); 
    $path=Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/uploads/'.$download->attachment;

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($path);
    }
}
```

in your grid view :

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'id'=>'mygrid',
'columns' => [
['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],



[
'attribute'=>'attachment',
'format'=>'raw',
'value' => function($data)
{
    return
    Html::a('Download file', ['letter/download', 'id' => $data->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);

}
],

],
]); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. It says undefined variable $model. Should I add this as a parameter or create global variable $model = new Letter()?

Comment: @VitalyPark updated controller code please check it now

Comment: Something gets wrong with if statement in form view. The part "isNewRecord):?>" seems in view like a simple text.

Comment: @VitalyPark please specify that error code or message.

Comment: <?if(!$model->isNewRecord):?>
<?= Html::a('Download file', ['download', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?endif;?>

Comment: something with this. Unfortunately I can't provide a screenshot of this issue. I am here using smartphone

Comment: are you sure your enable php short tags?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know. My php version is 5.6. How can I check it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: I opened this in a browser. What I have to do?

Comment: sry you can  check this link it shows how enable short tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: <?php if(!$model->isNewRecord):?>
<? echo Html::a('Download file', ['download', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php endif;?>

Comment: I enabled short tags, but when I press on download btn it says page not found. Also I need a link or a button to download file from grid view and in view.php. How can I implement this?

Comment: page not found you specify controllername/actionname in link

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: <?= Html::a('Download file', ['controllername/download', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

Comment: Do I need an Internet connection to download this file even my project is local?

Comment: it says page not found again..  I tried as  'LetterController/download', '/LetterController/download', '/LetterController/actionDownload/download'

Comment: <?= Html::a('Download file', ['letter/download', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

Comment: great! It works! Please advice how can I paste this into gridview and view.php?

Comment: sure i can help please upvote for this answer its useful for others

Comment: you mean to ask as a new question?

Comment: no i added how gridview work. in this question answer last part

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't see this. I will try it. Thanks so much!

Comment: thank you it works. How can I add this url into detailview widget in view.php?