# Wordpress template file started showing code

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have had a wp-template file that has worked for a year. Suddenly last night I started seeing some of the template code being printed out to the page:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat'=>-145, 'paged'=>$paged ) ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php /* The loop */ ?>
```

Anything above (and the footer) is working fine. However,I see code like this:
`10, 'cat'=>-145, 'paged'=>$paged ) ); ?>` ie a section of what I have been using.

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: to be clear is this code still same there without start <?php tag    ?                      $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat'=>-145, 'paged'=>$paged ) ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

There is must some html tag or double quotes " or single quote ' issue please check your file.

Comment: well, that's what I would have suspected - so I did look for that, and like I said its worked for a year. But I'll check again

Comment: May be you have just update your wordpress, php or mysql version on your server and that thing effect your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - but I found it

in the line above I had `<? code here` which worked before. If I now make it fuller by putting `<?php` it all works.

Comment: That's because de PHP configuration. Maybe you have the short_open_tag disabled? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: I never even knew about that, or what it was called! Thanks