# php if statement in html is matching all conditions

Tags: php

I'm trying to get an `if` statement to test a php session and if it's true, show html and if it's not, don't show html. I did some research and found this

```
<?
$a = 2; 
 if ($a == 2): ?>
  <p>Content</p>
<? elseif ($a == 3): ?>
  <p>Other Content</p>
<? else: ?>
  <p>Default Content</p>
<? endif; ?>
```

but when i run it, every condition seems to be met as it outputs everything, does anyone know why? thanks

[image: here]

Comment: Seems to work just fine? https://3v4l.org/EtDqA as expected - if it isn't your `short_open_tags` are off

Comment: you sure short tags are enabled?

Comment: and what do you see in html source; "code"?

Comment: thats weird, it doesnt work on mine, @fred what are short tags and how do i enable them?

Comment: Short tags disabled in your dev invironment - you have to use <?php instead of <?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2185320/3933332

Comment: @RachelDockter Just use full PHP tags, `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: @Rizier123 seems like a dupe. Edit: closed.

Comment: ohhhhh ok i used <?php and it worked lol, seems like a waste of a question now, thanks freddy and qirel

Comment: @RachelDockter See the duplicate the question was closed with, or use what the others suggested.