# PHP If/Else multiple condition not working as anticipated? Help me understand why?

Tags: php, html, validation, if-statement

I'm designing a web form to be used for customers to apply for a service upgrade. I'm currently stuck on an If/Else statement I have to test 
IF the dropdown is selected on "Ganged Positions*" AND the textbox gangPosition is blank.

This is so that **only** if they select "Ganged Positions" will the text box beside it need to be validated. IF this condition is true, I then want to validate the textbox to be numeric values only. Here is my code chunk

```
    //GANGED Position
    if($meterBase == "Ganged Position*" && $gangPosition == "")
        {
            $gangPositionError = "Positions Number required";
            $error = 1;
        }
         else if($gangPosition != "" && !is_numeric($gangPosition))
        {
            $gangPositionError = "Numbers Only";
            $error = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $gangPosition = $_POST['GangedPositions'];
            $gangPositionError = "";
            echo "THIS IS WORKING";
        }
```

**Currently** the initial double check works, it only spits an error if the "Ganged Positions*" is selected. But it just get's stuck in there and won't get rid of the error even if data  is entered. Here is the section of form where it takes place as a potential aid.

```
        <tr>
            <td align="right" id="meterbaselabel">Meter Base Location:</td>
            <td align="left">
                <select class="my_dropdown"  name="MeterBaseLocation" id="MeterBaseLocation"  style="width: 150px" title="Select the location of the Meter">
                    <option value="-1" selected>[select--location]</option>
                    <option <?php if($meterBase=="Existing Outside")      echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Existing Outside">Existing Outside</option>
                    <option <?php if($meterBase=="Inside Moving Out")     echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Inside Moving Out">Inside Moving Out</option>
                    <option <?php if($meterBase=="Relocate")              echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Relocate">Relocate</option>
                    <option <?php if($meterBase=="Ganged Position*")      echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Ganged Position*">Ganged Position*</option>
                </select>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" id="gangedPosition" name="GangedPositions" size="5" title="If meter location requires a Ganged (multiple) position installation, how many positions are needed?"/>*Positions</td>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><div align="center" class="error"><?php echo $meterBaseError;?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center" class="error"><?php echo $gangPositionError;?></div></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Why is `$gangPosition = $_POST['GangedPositions'];` in the `else` clause?  That assignment should be executed before the `if` statement.

Comment: New to web development, I was trying to make it such that the info wouldn't post unless it was valid. Meaning the form submit would bounce back unless everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to clean up your code.

1.) Enable php short open tags in your php.ini as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags). This will allow you to use `<?` instead of `<?php` in your html files.

2.) Simplify your if/else statements. Only the one else is needed.

The end result should be code that looks like this. I'm guessing you error occurred because you were checking `$gangPosition` before you were setting it.

```
$gangPosition = $_POST['GangedPositions'];
if ($meterBase === 'Ganged Position*' && !is_numeric($gangPosition)) {
    $gangPositionError = "Gang positions must be numeric."
    $error = 1;
    return false;//Depending on the rest of your code returning may not be needed.
}
```

Comment: Why should anyone want to use short tags?

Comment: Fewer characters to type and results in overall cleaner looking code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, new to web dev so I appreciate it. Your fix got me going, you're correct I was checking it before it was set. Can I ask what the triple '=' is accomplishing?

Comment: @AdamLee it's used to check types as well. It's a strict equal

Comment: @DarkBee Looking into it now, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @TheDude Cleaner looking code, if you don't use other similar-looking constructs such as XML processor instructions.