# LAMP Servers: find the differences

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

Preamble:

few years back I merged 2 opensource php project developing a part of the php code.

Problem:
I've this project running on ah hosting server with no hickups but when I try to run it in local (download via ftp all files locally) I guess there is some command which is not 100% compatible with my server settings and the only output I see is the part of a function I wrote.

This is part of the output:
    include.php
    funzione inserimento progetto
    "; $cancellazione_progetto = "Il progetto è stato cancellato solo in
    organizer
    "; $variazione_progetto = "Il nome del progetto è stato modificato
    "; $progetto_non_vuoto = "Il progetto non può essere cancellato perché 
    non vuoto
    "; $titolo_permessi_phpbb3 = "
    Inserimento permessi forum
    "; ################ #   Gestione attività ############### 
    $creazione_attivita ="Attività creata con successo\n"; 
    $no_nome_attivita = "Nome attività non 
    .
    .
    .

I can see that both servers (local and remote) run the same php version buth I can't figure out where and what is the difference.
Considering the output I believe that there should be no mysql problem involved otherwise I think I should read the error msg.

Locally I have other site/projects using php and mysql running smoothly, just this one bring me headache.

Does someone have a suggestion where I should look at?

Thanks

Comment: This particular project wouldn't be using short open tags, by any chance? I.e. `<?` instead of `<?php`? That could be disabled in your local php.ini file

Comment: I have no idea what your wall of text is supposed to say. I am guessing your saying: **Apache does not interpret my PHP code correctly**? - Check the **View Source** of your page and put the content in a paste of your choice. Afterwards you take the code of that page (All of it) and put it in a paste of your choice. Now put those links into your question. Then anybody might be able to give a solid answer.

Comment: I agree with rick, Check the situation with short hand tags:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: Secondly and less likely the issue in this case but worth remembering is watch out for case sensitivity, specially file names. Not a noticeable problem LAMP to WAMP but becomes a problem going WAMP to LAMP since windows is ignorant of case sensitivity on files where as Linux will pick up on the issue.

Comment: Hi there and thanks.
As I said the LAMP server works without problem. there are few php/Mysql applications running  and also the same project works on the hosting server so it is specificly a local problem.
I'll give a go with the short open tag. I believe it is the answer!!

keep you posted

Comment: Updates:
the issue I reported seams to be solved allowing the short open tag.

Next issue:
the main page returns blank on the browser. I checked the file where I figured out there was a problem with php -l nome_file (it was yesterday but I think the command is correct) giving me a syntax error as unexpected end of file.

Is there any other little setting I should be aware that my cause my code not to be interpreted as it is online?

Thankds