# PHP escaping <? ?>

Tags: php, html, syntax

I would not like to echo this code because I need to match the other syntax in my .php. How would I get this to work. I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution.

```html
<? if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0): ?>
    // output data of each row
  
<? while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
  <center><b><p>Order ID: " . $row['ID'] . "</p></b></center><br>
  <center><b><p>Order Total: " . $row['total'] . "</p></b></center><br>
  <center><b><p>Order Status: " . $row['status'] . "</p></b></center><br>
  <center><b><p>Payment Status: " . $row['payment'] . "</p></b></center><br>
<? endwhile ?>
 mysqli_close($conn);
<?php endif; ?>
```

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: So I've tried fixing it as you say, and it seems for some reason nothing is displaying when I run the code. :S

Comment: Update your question to display your latest coding attempt and turn on your errors and tells us what the error(s) are.  `mysqli_close($conn)` and those echo'ed `$row`s need to be inside of php as well.  You ALSO don't need the if statement, the while statement will handle this case.

Comment: You forgot `<?php` multiple times...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: Do you know that the query is error-free and that resultset actually holds some rows of data?  Is there an `else`?  Are you attempting to debug this with error checking?  Your question is at risk of being closed as "Off-topic: Why isn't this code working?"  Please update your question with the necessary information.

Comment: How do you know your code does not work? What is not working? Are you getting any errors? Have you tried running from the command line using `php myfile.php` to see if any errors are generated? Have you looked in the php logs to see what errors show up there?

Answer (score 2):

this might be a [short open tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) issue. Either change `<?` to `<?php` or configure php to allow short open tags

Answer (score 0):

Would that work?

```html
<center><b><p>Order ID: <?= $row['ID'] ?></p></b></center><br>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem so, I still get no output when running it live. v_v

Answer (score 0):

Try this let me know...

I thought you missed the following:

**`<? ... ?> into <?php ... ?>`**

**`endwhile missing semicolon(;)`**

**`mysqli_close without php tag`**

```
<?php if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0): ?>    

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
        <center><b><p>Order ID: <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>   </p></b></center><br>
        <center><b><p>Order Total: <?php echo $row['total']; ?> </p></b></center><br>
        <center><b><p>Order Status: <?php echo $row['status']; ?>   </p></b></center><br>
        <center><b><p>Payment Status: <?php echo $row['payment']; ?>    </p></b></center><br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php mysqli_close($conn); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!= 0): ?>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
        <center><b><p>Order ID: <?php echo $row['ID'] ?></p></b></center><br>
        <center><b><p>Order Total: <?php echo $row['total'] ?></p></b></center><br>
<? endwhile;
 mysqli_close($conn);
 endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please explain something

Comment: Here Same thing like >0 and !=0. Also defined php tag for print $row['ID']

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate the OP and future readers.  Do not explain your answer via comments.  Always explain your answer within the answer.