# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 php

Tags: php, json

hey there i have an issue with my php coding i think, i am getting 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

during the success part of a jquery ajax form post. the php code is sending me back

```
<?



?>{"Status":"Login Success"}
```

the php code is as follows

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    //Load DB Connection
    require('Global.php');
    require('dbConnect.php');
    require('Studio7WebClass.php');


    //Get form data
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $returnJSON = array('Status'=>'');
    $finalJSON = "";
    $Studio7Current = new Studio7Web;

    $Studio7Current->set_username($username);

        try{
            $statement = $conn->prepare("select * from Users where (Username = :name OR EmailAddress = :name)");
            $statement->execute(array(':name' => $username));
            $row = $statement->fetch();

            if (is_null($row)){
                $returnJSON['Status'] = "User Not Found";
                    $finalJSON = json_encode($returnJSON);
            }
            else{

                //Now check if the password matches the one the user entered.
                if($row['password'] == $password){
                    //Passwords match
                    $returnJSON['Status'] = "Login Success";
                    $finalJSON = json_encode($returnJSON);

                }else{

                    $returnJSON['Status'] = "Password Error";
                    $finalJSON =  json_encode($returnJSON);
                }

            }



        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $returnJSON['Status'] =  $e->getMessage();
            $finalJSON =  json_encode($returnJSON);
            file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);

        }       

    echo $finalJSON;

    ?>
```

i have no idea why im getting the response it gives. please help

Comment: If `<?` is sent back in the AJAX response, the error is obvious...

Comment: LOL please elaborate im a fairly new php coder ;)

Comment: `<?` shouldn't be coming back if it's a `JSON` response ..

Comment: ive set the header to json and it still responds with <?

Comment: Do all the files that you required have code?

Comment: I don't think you should set the `header` -> just return the response in `JSON` format

Comment: turns out that Global.php require was an empty php file and it was putting that into the response... ive removed that require block and its sending valid json now :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this file uses `<?php` and not just `<?` as opening tags, the output comes from another file. You could either find that file and remove those 5 lines, or enable short tags (see [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)).

Comment: short tags are enabled by default with majority of PHP versions nowadays - this wasn't the issue :)