# Getting PHP Code in broswer while installing Bitexchange script

Tags: php

I am trying to Install Bitexhchange script on Localhost, after successfully doing all changes, I am getting PHP code in my browser

[image]

[bitexchnage support page](http://support.bitexchange.systems/support/sections/backend-and-web-app-installation).

```
<?
include 'lib/common.php';
ini_set("memory_limit","200M");
$CFG->print = $_REQUEST['print'];
$CFG->url = ($_REQUEST['current_url'] != 'index.php') ? ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z_\-]", "",$_REQUEST['current_url']) : '';
$CFG->action = ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z_\-]", "",$_REQUEST['action']);
$CFG->bypass = ($_REQUEST['bypass'] || $CFG->print);
$CFG->is_tab = (!$CFG->url) ? 1 : $_REQUEST['is_tab'];
$CFG->id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "",$_REQUEST['id']);
$CFG->target_elem = ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z_\-]", "",$_REQUEST['target_elem']);
$CFG->in_popup = ($CFG->target_elem == 'edit_box' || $CFG->target_elem == 'message_box' || $CFG->target_elem == 'attributes box');
$CFG->inset_id = false;
$_SESSION['last_query'] = $_SESSION['this_query'];
$_SESSION['this_query'] = 'index.php?'.http_build_query((is_array($_POST)) ? $_POST : $_GET);

date_default_timezone_set($CFG->default_timezone);
String::magicQuotesOff();
```

Comment: can you show the code you use ?

Comment: Did you enable PHP support in your web server?

Comment: @Raptor yes i enabled,...

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ i attached the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your php is probably not configured to accept the short open tags (`<?`)

You should either enable it into your php.ini file (see [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags) ) or use the "long" php open tag : `<?php`

Comment: always use standard PHP open tag `<?php` to avoid such problem, applicable for all PHP versions.