# Title Counter Function Not Work for WordPress, Error 500

Tags: wordpress, function

Before this I never get any problem using this code on my WordPress function, but by this month my error because of this code.Can someone detect the problem?
You can try put this on your WordPress function.php . It's used to be count counter

```
<?php

function my_title_count(){ ?>
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#titlediv .inside").after("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:40px;right:-5px;\"><span>Max 57 characters:</span> <input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" maxlength=\"3\" size=\"3\" id=\"title_counter\" readonly=\"\" style=\"background:none;border:none;box-shadow:none;font-weight:bold; text-align:right;\"></div>");
jQuery("#title_counter").val(jQuery("#title").val().length);
jQuery("#title").keyup( function() {
jQuery("#title_counter").val(jQuery("#title").val().length);
});
});
</script>
<? }
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'my_title_count');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'my_title_count');
?>

<?php function my_excerpt_count(){ ?>
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#postexcerpt .handlediv").after("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:4px;right:25px;\"><span>Max 156 characters:</span> <input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" maxlength=\"3\" size=\"3\" id=\"excerpt_counter\" readonly=\"\" style=\"background:none;border:none;box-shadow:none;font-weight:bold; text-align:right;\"></div>");
jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
jQuery("#excerpt").keyup( function() {
jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
});
});
</script>
<? }
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'my_excerpt_count');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'my_excerpt_count');
?>
```

source: http://passwordincorrect.com/add-character-count-to-title-and-excerpt-in-wordpress-post-editor/

Comment: Can you check your server's error log and let me know the error?

Comment: wait, I have to figure out how to get error log in google cloud

Comment: sorry, I can't get any error log from my Php error log

Comment: Remove PHP closing & beginning tags between both the functions and try.

Comment: Done, no error and not getting 500 again, but this not work to get title counter

Comment: What is your WordPress version? Have you upgraded recently?

Comment: I use WordPress the latest and host it at Google Cloud..previously I use normal shared hosting, dont get any problem

Comment: I am too not sure because working fine for me, try checking JS console for errors if any.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6079c49f2cd09e5b2074f667bd7394fc552f1216

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() in [...][...]:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

Comment: <? is old style PHP depending on php.ini it may not be understoood. Use <?php instead.

Comment: @magenta may be correct, change the tags to `<?php` or enable PHP short tag as per - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags.

Comment: Great! Thank you @magenta ..it's work now

Comment: Yes Magenta correct..thank to @OutsourceWordPress too, up this post