# The xampp server does not work with the following code but the code works on appserv

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, xampp

The xampp server does not work with the following code

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("Location:Home.php");
exit();
}else{ ?> hi dear<? } ?>
```

but the code works on appserv 
In Server Xampp I have a problem with the appearance of pages not formatted like this 
and i have to do this code such that

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("Location:Home.php");
exit();
}else{ echo" hi dear"; } ?>
```

what is the solve?

Comment: I do not really understand your question. You want to remove the `echo "hi dear";` and replace it with `?> hi dear<?`? Why in the first place? Try using the correct php opening `?> hi dear <?php`.

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2185331/5255147) answer

Comment: no this is example for problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in my projects that code is not working with short php tags `<?`, try to replace them with standard ones `<?php`. And give it a shot. Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Did u type *session_start();* on the top of the document?

Could u provide the error thet PHP shows?

Take it out of the IF and see if it works

on my document i have this:

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
    Header( 'Location: ../index.php' ) 
    exit
    }else{
       echo 'hello world';
    }
```

Comment: <?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?> At the beginning of the page

Answer (score 0):

Try This One. It will work.

```
<?
   if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      header("Location:Home.php");
      exit();
   }else{ ?> 
      <?= hi dear" ?> 
<? } ?>
```