# background-color does weird things

Tags: php, html, background-color

I just want to change the background color on my simple site.
But it's not only non functional, it's changing the background to red, even if i completly delete all coloring, restart XAMMP and delete the browser chache.
I'm completly clueless.
And yes.. I know that the code is not efficient, but it was my task to do it that way.

```
<html>
<head><title>Switch</title></head>
<body>
<p><div id="main">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<?php
$Uhrzeit = date("H");

echo '<body style="background-color:blue" />'; //Even set the color outside the if-statement

if($Uhrzeit > 6 && $Uhrzeit <= 12){
    echo '<body style="background-color:blue" />';
}
elseif($Uhrzeit > 12 && $Uhrzeit <= 18){
    echo '<body style="background-color:blue" />';
}
elseif($Uhrzeit > 18 && $Uhrzeit < 6){
    echo '<body style="background-color:black" />';
    echo '<body style="color:white" />';
}

$select = $_POST["Monat"];

switch($select){                                            
case "Januar":                                          
    echo $select . " hat 31 Tage";
    break;
case "Februar":
    echo $select . " hat 28 Tage";
    break;
case "März":
    echo $select . " hat 31 Tage";
    break;
case "April":
    echo $select . " hat 30 Tage";
    break;
case "Mai":
    echo $select . " hat 31 Tage";
    break;
case "Juni":
    echo $select . " hat 30 Tage";
    break;
case "Juli":
    echo $select . " hat 31 Tage";
    break;
case "August":
    echo $select . " hat 31 Tage";
    break;
case "September":
    echo $select . " hat 30 Tage";
    break;
case "Oktober":
    echo $select . " hat 31 Tage";
    break;
case "November":
    echo $select . " hat 30 Tage";
    break;
default:
    echo $select . " hat 31 Tage";
    break;
}
?>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="submit" href="#" onclick="history.back()" value="Zurück">
</div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your first echo of the body is missing a ";" char at the end. And why printing the body tag before your if statements? the `<body>` tag can only be once in an HTML document and it should not be self-closed like `<body />`. It should have your page content inside. Check at a [minimal HTML5 code template](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-minimal-html-document-html5-edition/) to understand what I mean. Also, what happens if you load the page without a POST? `$select = isset($_POST['Monat']) ?? '';`  would remove the PHP error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be only one `body` tag in the HTML document. You are printing many, so that's the issue. Instead of `echo '<body...'` you could store the color in a variable and print it in main `body` tag.

Example:

```
<?php

$bgColor = 'blue';

if(something) {
    $bgColor = 'red';
} else if (something) {
    $bgColor = 'yellow';
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Switch</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: <?php echo $bgColor; ?>">

...

</body>
</html>
```

Or if you have [short_open_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags) enabled in php config, you could replace `<?php echo $bgColor; ?>` with `<?=$bgColor;?>`

Comment: Thank you! I'll do it that way in the future, but it doesn't fix that the background-color is constantly red. (Even if I don't have any red coloring)

Comment: If you follow my advices, it should work. If not, the red probably comes not from the code that you provided.