# PHP is installed and running but not loading on page

Tags: php, apache

I have recently installed Apache, MySQL and PHP, but the page is not loading the PHP code, it's interpreted as HTML comment. All services are enabled but haven't got a clue what's going on. Obviously is not possible to reproduce my localhost environment.

I am on Linux Mint 20 and latest Apache/MySQL/PHP.

Does anyone know how to make PHP work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP tags are the short ones. In order to enable them, you need to change `short_open_tag=On` in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), or just write `<?php` instead of `<?`.

```
///BONUS : the short tag '<?=' can be used without editing the php.ini. It's shorter than:
<?php echo $var; ?>

<?= $var; ?>
```

Comment: It worked, I never heard about this option! thank you!