# How does the question mark (<?) tag work in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Sometimes I see question mark tags in html, like this.

```
<? /* JavaScript code goes here*/ ?>
```

The browser turns these question mark tags into html comments, like this.

```js
// javascript

console.log(document.querySelector("div").innerHTML);
```

```html
<!--html-->

<div>
  <? console.log("this is javascript") ?>
</div>
```

Editors like vscode even syntax highlight the code inside these `<?` tags. But let's say I have code inside these tags like this.

```js
x.map(function(item){return + item + '<li></li>'}).join('')
```

This is how it renders:

```js
// javascript

console.log(document.querySelector("div").innerHTML);
```

```html
<!--html-->

<div>
  <?
    x.map(function(item) {
      return + item + '<li></li>'
    }).join("");
  ?>
</div>
```

**So how do these question mark tags work?** Is it even valid HTML?

Comment: This is php Are you using PHP as your servercode? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use#:~:text=There%20are%20four%20different%20pairs,can%20be%20used%20in%20PHP.

Comment: Looks like PHP being rendered on the page by mistake - perhaps you need to [enable short opening tags in PHP.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Comment: And this is the browser attempting to close the start angle bracket: `<?
    x.map(function(item) {
      return + item + '<li></li>` <<<<

Comment: This is not php: this is raw HTML

Comment: That is PHP syntax, and doesn't belong in client-side HTML in your browser.

Comment: It's called a "bogus comment" by the HTML parser. It's not valid.