# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "public"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm facing an issue:

The code below is part of a plugin, when I try and activate this plugin I get the error PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "public" which refers to snippet below. I am using PHP 8.1 and if I change it to 7.1 it activates without issue.

```
public function render_commission_inputs_for_wcv($item)
{
    if (
        is_wcv_pro_active() &&
        Multi_Vendor_Campaign_Campaigns::is_mvc_pro_active()
    ) {
        // If WC Vendor Pro and Multi-vendor Campaign Pro is active
        do_action('mvc_wcvendors_pro_inputs', $item);
    } else if (
        is_wcv_pro_active() &&
        !Multi_Vendor_Campaign_Campaigns::is_mvc_pro_active()
    ) {
        // If WC Vendor Pro is active but Multi-vendor Campaign Pro is not active
        // In this situation, only support percentage commission type
        $commission_type = get_option('wcvendors_commission_type', 'percent');
        if ($commission_type === 'percent') {
    ?>
            <tr class="form-field">
                <th scope="row"><label for="commission_percentage"><?php esc_html_e('Extra Commission Percentage', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></label></th>
                <td class="fields"><input name="commission_percentage" type="number" id="commission_percentage" value="<?php echo esc_attr($item['commission_percentage']); ?>" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" maxlength="60" class="labeled_input_number" required>
                    <span class="input_number_label">
                        <span class="negative"><?php esc_html_e('You, the site admin, get', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></span>
                        <span class="positive"><?php esc_html_e('vendors get', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></span>
                        <span class="value"><?php echo esc_attr($item['commission_percentage']); ?></span>
                        <span class="more"><?php esc_html_e('% more', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="help">
                    <p><?php esc_html_e('The Commission percentage that be added to original commission percentage. This value could be positive, negative, or zero.', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        } else {
            // If MVC Pro is not active show unsupported message
        ?>
            <tr class="form-field">
                <th style="color: crimson;" scope="row">Unsupported Commission Type</label></th>
                <td class="fields">
                    <p> <?php printf(
                            esc_html__(
                                'We only support for Percent commission type in our free version. Please upgrade to PRO version to unlock support for %s commission type.',
                                'multi_vendor_campaign'
                            ),
                            $commission_type
                        ); ?> </p>
                </td>
                <td class="help">
                    <p><?php esc_html_e('You can change your commission type from: WP Dashboard > WC Vendors > Settings > Commission > Global Commission Type', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    } else if (!is_wcv_pro_active()) {
        // WC Vendor free version
        ?>
        <!--commissionPercentage-->
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row"><label for="commission_percentage"><?php esc_html_e('Extra Commission Percentage', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></label></th>
            <td class="fields"><input name="commission_percentage" type="number" id="commission_percentage" value="<?php echo esc_attr($item['commission_percentage']); ?>" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" maxlength="60" class="labeled_input_number" required>
                <span class="input_number_label">
                    <span class="negative"><?php esc_html_e('You, the site admin, get', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></span>
                    <span class="positive"><?php esc_html_e('vendors get', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></span>
                    <span class="value"><?php echo esc_attr($item['commission_percentage']); ?></span>
                    <span class="more"><?php esc_html_e('% more', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="help">
                <p><?php esc_html_e('The Commission percentage that be added to original commission percentage. This value could be positive, negative, or zero.', 'multi_vendor_campaign'); ?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why this happening. I would post the entire code but the file is 1511 lines long.

Comment: The problem is likely *above* the line shown: because of how it's interpreted the previous part of the file, PHP isn't expecting the next method yet, which is why it reports the "public" as unexpected.

Comment: Wild guess: it's nothing to do with PHP version, but the script uses a "short open tag" somewhere, so you need to [turn those on in your new php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags).

Comment: Is this the offending plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-vendor-campaign/  It's not being maintained. You probably need to stay with php7 to use it.

Comment: Hi @O.Jones yes that is the plugin. I've change the php version back to 7.2 and it's working and actually some other errors that Wordpress was given have also resolved themselves. I will remain on PHP 7.2 for now. Thanks

Comment: @IMSoP is correct. On line 301 of that file is a short open tag at the end of the line. `?><script>document.title = "<?php echo esc_attr($item['title']).' < '.str_replace('-', ' ', ucwords($this->plugin_name, '-')) ?>";</script><?`. Changing it to `<?php` fixes the error.