# include_once shown contents of file instead of execute code

Tags: php, include

I have php script **test.php**

```
<?php
defineDocumentRoot();

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/common/common.php');
RegisterModule('main');

function defineDocumentRoot(){
   
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']= dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/public_html';

}
```

function **RegisterModule** defined in common.php

```
function RegisterModule($name) {
    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/common/modules/$name/include.php")) {
        include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/common/modules/$name/include.php");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

And main module **include.php** file

```
<?
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/CommonObject.php');  
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/Callback.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/AdminSecurity.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/Site.php');
```

When i run php test.php i got following output:

```
<?
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/CommonObject.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/Callback.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/AdminSecurity.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/Site.php');
```

The test.php susccesfuly got function registerModule after including common.php.

But when function RegisterModule should to include  the main module include.php file by following code

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/common/modules/$name/include.php");
```

seems like that function just return contents of file instead of including it.

when scripts running via nginx its works fine.The problem i got meets up only in cli

Comment: the code is legacy and all project is huge to refactor.I create new files with <?php

Comment: Try using `<?php` in these files as well, does that resolve issue?

Comment: Yes,that helps.Is there anyway stay with <?. I dont really wont to rewrite all project code :\

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags but really you should use the full tags.. Maybe you could use `sed` and replace all of them in code base.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Seems like problem was that that flag was enabled in htacces and dont enable in php.ini

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)